# FIFO queue for Producer Consumer Problem Not Working

Tags: c, semaphore, producer-consumer, fifo

I currently am trying to implement FIFO for the producer consumer problem. However when I run the code it seems that the first item is not being removed from the buffer as the output shows that every consumer is consuming the first item and never the others (Screenshot of output attached).

I implemented a LIFO queue and got the expected result which is what leads me to believe that the issue is with my FIFO implementation.

Comment: can we have a complete program that we can compile and test please

Comment: @pm100 edited to include everything

Comment: `return` stops the function

Comment: @user253751 are you referring to the return 0 in the dequeue function?

Comment: buffer_index is misnamed, its message_count ( a count of the number of messages)  - took me a while

Comment: seems to run fine for me, can you post the 'bad ' output (you say there is a screen shot but there isnt one)

Comment: @pm100 I attached the screenshots along with updates to the code the changes I made seem to be on the right track however as you can see in the screenshot the consumer seems to be consuming nothing for a bit

Comment: I will posy my output as an answer - even though its not an answer and I will get heat for that. I ran it under valgrind too to see if any UB, valgrind gives it a clean bill of health

Comment: @pm100 I mistakenly posted my LIFO implementation in the beginning and edited it. I was wondering if you were using the updated insert and dequeue methods

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple error in dequeue. Imagine you want to get the first entry in the queue ( buffer_rd == 0). But you increment buffer_rd and the read theat entry,

```
buffer_t dequeuebuffer() {
    if (buffer_rd == buffer_wr) {
        printf("Buffer underflow\n");
    } else {
        buffer_rd = (buffer_rd + 1) % SIZE; <<<<<====
         return buffer[buffer_rd];   <<<<<<======
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you need to reverse those 2 (like in insert)

```
buffer_t dequeuebuffer() {
    if (buffer_rd == buffer_wr) {
        printf("Buffer underflow\n");
    } else {
        int ret =  buffer[buffer_rd];
        buffer_rd = (buffer_rd + 1) % SIZE;

    return ret;
    }


    return 0;
}
```